# NameError: name 'btnEqualsInput' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, calculator

**I'M making calculator on python.l'll trying to  more times to define but Incorrect.How can define btnEqualsInput**

```
 from tkinter import*

    def btnclick (numbers):
        global operator
        operator=operator + str(numbers)
        text_Input.set(operator)

    def btnClearDisplay():
        global operator
        operator=""
        text_Input.set("")
cal = Tk()
cal.title("Mr.calculator")
operator=""
text_Input =StringVar()

btnEquals=Button(cal,padx=16,bd=8, fg="black",font=('arial',20,'bold'),
                    text="=",bg="powder blue",command=btnEqualsInput).grid(row=4,column=2)
```

Error....

```
 text="=",bg="powder blue",command=btnEqualsInput).grid(row=4,column=2)
NameError: name 'btnEqualsInput' is not defined
```

Comment: Show your full code for accurate answer.

Comment: Please reduce and enhance this into the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  The error message is quite clear: you tried to use a symbol you haven't yet defined.

Comment: You said right... I now all the codes this project because my 1 st project same as well as  earler 2 years ago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is the proper define btnEqualsInput. try this**

```
def btnClearDisplay():
        global operator
        operator=""
        text_Input.set("")
```

adding after this.this is define buuton Equals

```
def btnEqualsInput():
     global operator
     sumup=str(eval(operator))
     text_Input.set(sumup)
     operator=""
```

Comment: How can you be certain of this, when OP didn't define the problem at all?  The small amount of code in the question isn't even a legal statement, so you have no way of knowing what the `command` parameter requires.

Comment: Thank you for Solution, It's working, I really appreciate you...you everytime helping me...